# Converting a string month in to an integer aka may to 5 within android studio

Tags: java

How can I simply convert a string containing a variable of a month to a integer value?

I can do something like below but it seems like there should be a more efficient method to do so.

```java
int month_int;
        switch (month) {//3 letter string input
            case "Jan":  month_int= 1; break;
            case "Feb":  month_int= 2; break;
            case "Mar":  month_int= 3; break;
            case "Apr":  month_int= 4; break;
            case "May":  month_int= 5; break;
            case "Jun":  month_int= 6; break;
            case "Jul":  month_int= 7; break;
            case "Sep":  month_int= 9; break;
            case "Oct":  month_int= 10;break;
            case "Nov":  month_int= 11;break;
            case "Dec":  month_int= 12;break;
            default:   month_int= 0; break;//Error
        }
        return month_int;
```

My input is a three letter string which I need to be converted to an int. Aka 1-12.

Comment: how about: case "Jan" ... you already have what you want, what more do you need?

Comment: Is that `String` lower-case or upper-case or just the first letter upper-case? How about involving `java.time.Month`? What is the purpose of this code snippet? Is that an entire method? Where and why are you using it? I bet you will never get a `4` returned when you have a `case "Arp"` in this `switch`...

Comment: @ADM yes but I am already using the calendar library and using an sdf already but can't change the data as that is how I receive it. Unless there is a way to use the calendar format to convert from one from format to another.

Comment: Are you receiving the date in some complete format? ISO? or you have just the month?

Comment: Please consider using `java.time` instead of the outdated `java.util.Calendar` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Why do you think this code snippet is not efficient?

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi I have the complete format it is just the month I want to convert as the rest I can just parse differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the incoming format is [ISO MMM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), go with that

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter MONTH_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", Locale.ENGLISH); // supports Jan, Feb etc
MONTH_FORMAT.parse("Feb").get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR); // 2
Month month = Month.from(MONTH_FORMAT.parse("Feb")); // java.time.Month.FEBRUARY
```

It's easy to get the month number (2) but likely better to get the `Month` enum as that encourages you to continue using java.time API solve calendar problems!

Comment: This looks like a reasonnable answer on principle (if your statement that the input is ISO MMM holds). But the locale here plays a crucial role.Trying to recognize "Feb" may fail (it would work in spanish and english, but not in french, nor obviously, in any non latin language). And you should check for exceptions.

Comment: Yes, @GPI is right... Just add the `Locale` to the call to `ofPattern` and this will be the best answer imho. Do `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", Locale.ENGLISH)`...

Comment: Updated, thanks - I did think about Locale but skipped over it!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Map of String to Month values where String is the key you're looking for and Month is the relative month to the key.

```java
Map<String, Month> monthsByDisplay = Stream.of(Month.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH), Function.identitity());
    

Month month = monthsByDisplay.get("Jan");

if (month == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("unexpected date key");
}
int monthValue = month.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use java.time.Month Enum (See javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html)). method `getValue()` will give you your numeric value of the month 1 - 12